# Remove whitespaces from a url in Urlpatterns (django)

Tags: python, django, url, whitespace

I'm new to Django and I'm developing a project in which there are profile pages.

Well, the problem is that the primary key has whitespaces but I don't want them to show in the url, neither like "%20%", I want to join the words. For example:

website.com/Example Studios --> website.com/examplestudios

I've tried this:

```
url ( (r'^(?P<studio_name>[\w ]+)/$').replace(" ", ""), views.StudioView, name = 'dev_profile')
```

But didn't work (it seems like it turns the raw part to string before reading the url) and with 're' happens the same. I've been searching for solutions but I'm not able to find them (and slugify doesn't convinces me).

What's solution to this or what do you recommend?

Comment: In urls you define patterens which Django will catch e.g. r'^test/$' this means that when someone try to get yourdomain.com/test Django will catch it and call the view which will probably render template. You need to solve your problem on url generation e.g. in template <a href='/products/1'></a>. Therefore in urls:
url ( (r'^(?P<studio_name>[\w ]+)/$'), views.StudioView, name = 'dev_profile'). You need to transform primary key to word without space in template. One way is to use slug for every record.

Comment: <a href="{% url 'dev_profile' studio.slug %}"></a>
Also add slug field to Studio model which is autogenerated and non-editable field(you can generate it from name e.g. Example Studios->examplestudios).

Comment: Okay, I achieved to set the slug but now I have another problem, I was calling the studio_name in the template through a intermediate table this way: user.admin.studio_name (the db scheme is something like this: User-->Admin<--Studio). Now I don't know how to declare a variable that store the Studio model so I can call the slug.

Comment: Can you show me your code of your models and view which renders template maybe?

Comment: Well, I won't complicate myself, I set the slug primarykey and it looks like it works.

Comment: Can I post my comments as answer?

Comment: sure, you helped me a lot I think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In urls you define patterens which Django will catch e.g. r'^test/$' this means that when someone try to get yourdomain.com/test Django will catch it and call the view which will probably render template. You need to solve your problem on url generation e.g. in template . Therefore in urls:
`url ( (r'^(?P<studio_name>[\w ]+)/$'), views.StudioView, name = 'dev_profile')`.
You need to transform primary key to word without space in template. One way is to use slug for every record.
 Also add slug field to Studio model which is autogenerated and non-editable field(you can generate it from name e.g. Example Studios->examplestudios).